# Difference in SQL query result from Tableau dashboard

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

I have an issue where the following query

```
WITH SumByUid AS (
  SELECT
    Uid,
    SUM(Value) AS TotalValue
  FROM
    your_table
 WHERE day between '2023-08-01' and '2023-08-15'
  GROUP BY
    Uid
)

SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS UserCountUnderThreshold
FROM
  SumByUid
WHERE
  TotalValue < 600000;
```

Returns a value  of = 40k+

But comparing on tableau with the formulars below returned 89K+ After filtering by date within the specified date range i.e `'2023-08-01' and '2023-08-15'`

```
TotalValueUser = { FIXED [User Id] : sum([Value])} 

ActiveUsers = if [TotalValuebyUser] > 600000 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

Comment: It seems you are querying for the number of users with a value of less than 600k in sql and returning 'YES' for users with greater than 600k value in tableau, what is the count of your 'NO' occurrences?

Comment: @MUFF...that was an error, I'm querying for >600k for both

Comment: Are you bringing aggregated data into tableau such as TotalValue from your query? If so, it is possible that you could be adding these values again in your tableau calculation, which would be close to your 89k occurrences. Also are there any other filters you have applied to your query, but not your tableau book?

Comment: There is no other filter aside from the data filter.  I will check for the aggregated data. Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: @MUFF. thanks, I was able to figure it out. Turns out the value column on big query was already aggregated. I didn't have to sum it up again.  Appreciate your contributions.

Comment: Of course, glad I was able to help! I posted an answer to summarize these comments, feel free to accept and close the question if you so choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TotalValue column was being aggregated twice; once in your query, and then again in Tableau causing the discrepancy.